# Puedo llenar un Array con variables ya definidas?

Tags: c#, array, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp

Tengo la siguiente clase

```
public ActionResult RegistoPersonas( PostulantesVisado Visado)
        {
            string[] Personas = new string[17];
            Personas[0] = Visado.Nombre;
            Personas[1] = Visado.Apellido;
            Personas[2] = Visado.Nacionalidad;
            Personas[3] = Visado.Sexo;
...
```

Quiero saber como puedo llenar todos los espacios del array con algún ciclo

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si todos los espacios del array llevan distintos valores, un ciclo no sirve nada para. un ciclo sirve cuando sabes de antemano que valores van a llevar.

Comment: Igual, cabe destacar que si podrias hacer esto, si tu objeto heredara de la Interfaz IIterable, y tuviera todos los metodos que necesita esa interfaz (ademas de tener un yield en el metodo next)

Comment: Mmm... Okay Muchas Gracias !

Comment: Hola, podrías indicar la clase `PostulantesVisado` ?. Y otra cosa, por que **17** la dimensión del array? es un ejemplo o tiene que ser 17 siempre.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de llegar a lo que buscas hacer, es implementando la interface [`IEnumerable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.IEnumerable);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8).

Para hacerlo, deberás implementar el método `GetEnumerator` de esta interfaz.

Por ejemplo

```
//Heredo de IEnumerable.
public class ClaseIterable : IEnumerable
{
    //Creo dos propiedades a modo de prueba..
    public string PropiedadUno { get; set; }
    public string PropiedadDos { get; set; }

    //Implemento el método.
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        //En la primer iteración de foreach devolverá PropiedadUno.
        yield return PropiedadUno;
        //En la segunda, PropiedadDos.
        yield return PropiedadDos;
    }
}
```

Ahora, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
//Creo una instancia de la clase, y asigno las propiedades.
ClaseIterable test = new ClaseIterable();
test.PropiedadUno = "Prop 1";
test.PropiedadDos = "Prop 2";

//Uso foreach para iterar mi objeto    
foreach (var item in test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

El resultado será:

> ```
> Prop 1
> Prop 2
> ```

Cabe aclarar, que en el ejemplo anterior, item será de tipo `object`, en caso de que prefieras usar otro tipo, te recomiendo que uses [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es "cargar" en un **array** de strings las **propiedades** de una clase dada (en tu caso `PostulantesVisado`), podrías usar un bucle `for` para recorrer las propiedades, y mediante **Reflection** asignar el valor de la propiedad.

El código sería así:

```
    using System.Reflection;        

    ...

    public ActionResult RegistoPersonas( PostulantesVisado Visado)
    {
        string[] Personas = new string[17];

        PropertyInfo[] Propiedades = typeof(PostulantesVisado).GetProperties();

        for (int i = 0; i < Propiedades.Length && i < Personas.Length; i++)
        {
            Personas[i] = Propiedades[i].GetValue(Visado).ToString();
        }

     ...
```